# "{:02x}" can't results pairwise hex format for 239557639

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, number-formatting

```
  >>> "{:02x}".format(13)
     '0d'
  >>> "{:02x}".format(239557639)
    'e475c07'
```

I know this format result the hex in pair wise. It also works for another integer but not works for `239557639`

Actually, I want to do following with the output

```
>>> bytearray.fromhex('e475c07')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 7
>>> bytearray.fromhex('0e475c07')
bytearray(b'\x0eG\\\x07')
>>>
```

Comment: I don't understand your definition of "not working". Did you maybe expect to get `'0e 47 5c 07'` as output?

Comment: @Aran-Fey yes, I want this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it might be an issue with your hex number formatting. Try `{:08x}`:

```
>>> bytearray.fromhex('{:08x}'.format(239557639))
bytearray(b'\x0eG\\\x07')
```

Answer (score 1):

A more generic function to make a printable byte-aligned hex-string for an integer:

```
def aligned_hex_string(number, align_by=2):
    length = len(format(number, 'x'))
    mod = length % align_by
    return format(number, '0{}x'.format(length + align_by - mod) if mod else 'x')

print(aligned_hex_string(13))
print(aligned_hex_string(255))
print(aligned_hex_string(256))
print(aligned_hex_string(239557639))
print(aligned_hex_string(239557, 4))
```

Output:

```
0d
ff
0100
0e475c07
0003a7c5
```